# cart_payment.list does not return all payment methods in magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to use `cart_payement.list` api to retrieve the payment methods. But it only returns `checkmo` and `credit card` option. The enabled methods are `checkmo`, `credit card`, `Payu checkout`.

But In my frontend on the checkout page I am able to see all the 3 payment methods.

How do I get the payment methods to show?

Answer (score 0):

I know store is optional for that call but are you passing it? I've seen that fix a similar situation for cart_shipping.list

Comment: yes i have passed the store id in all the cart methods. But still it does not display all the options